# Can I hide a Trello List?

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Is there a way to hide & unhide a Trello list?

Or is there another kind of work around?

Answer (score 10):

Chrome users can use the "[Trellists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trellists-trello-lists-ma/dgnlcodfeenegnifnpcabcclldoceeml?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog)" extension:

- Adds a nice bar at the top where all existing lists are shown
- Hide and show lists at board by clicking list name in the bar

GitHub: https://github.com/VladSavitsky/trellists

Comment: Always include important contents of link in your answer.

Comment: This is a great little extension, exactly what I wanted. It does one thing and does it well, gets 5 ★ from me.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

There's a similar question on stackexchange here, where Rich Armstrong of Trello mentions a proposed collapsible lists Trello feature you can vote on:

[How do I hide and show entire tasks lists in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/how-do-i-hide-and-show-entire-tasks-lists-in-trello)

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the only way to "hide" a list is to archive it.

[image: Archive List on the List Popup Menu]

You can view your archived cards and lists by clicking the **"View Archived Items"** button on the right side of the board.

[image]

Comment: No I don't want it to go to Archive but rather just hide it from the other Lists.  It can still be opened/viewed as the items are still active.  Archive is where we place our perm. closed cards so it become a nightmare to find something.

Answer (score 1):

You can slide it all the way to the right so that if you have more than the ~5 lists that fit in the screen it will not be visible - but still active and accessible.

Another option: if you don't have a lot of cards you could add a label "Active" to the cards in the other lists and filter for that label.

Comment: Thanks!  But that is a no workie too.  It still visible.

Comment: Hmmmmmm....I like this idea!  Thanks!!!!!

Comment: +1 for options that work today even though they are not true full solutions.

Answer (score 1):

I needed this myself, so I wrote https://github.com/shesek/trello-hide-lists. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that still has this problem there is a simple solution - **stylish**. It's available for Chrome and Firefox and allows you to write custom styles for websites.

There are plenty ready-to-use ones like "Trello card id's" etc..

By adding the following to your style you can hide nth list from the view

```
.js-list.list-wrapper:nth-child(XXX){
    display:none;
}
```

where XXX is your list number (from left to right)

You can add this for every list you want to hide. Or make it match more than one element.

More examples with selectors here: [Useful :nth-child Recipes - CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/useful-nth-child-recipies/).