# How do I hide and show entire tasks lists in Trello?

Tags: trello, trello-lists

Does anyone knows how can we hide and show entire tasks lists in Trello, or if not possible, if it will be done nearly?

The problem is, that you have a list of 5 or 6 columns, but some of them need to get out of our sight while working, however, we must be able to check them a few times.

Plus, if you have only 4 for instance, it wouldn't be nice to *not* have them to narrow for comfortable reading.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not possible now, but as Rich Armstrong (Director of Customer Operations at Fog Creek Software, the makers of Trello) pointed out in his comment there is a feature request called ***Collapsible Lists*** which you can support by e-mailing **feature-ideas@trello.com**.

Comment: Looking at this, a decade later, and it's still not available...

Answer (score 6):

Use Trellists Chrome Extension.  It puts a directory of all lists within a board at the top of the screen.  You can toggle their visibility from there.

[Trellists - Chrome AddOn](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trellists-trello-lists-ma/dgnlcodfeenegnifnpcabcclldoceeml/related?hl=en-US)

Comment: I tried to get this working, but don't see anything in the trello view.  And Add-on page doesn't seem to provide much instructions

Answer (score 3):

I, too, needed this functionality, and wrote my own Chrome extension to help with this.

[Collapsible Trello Lists](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/collapsible-trello-lists/kejemfjfgoaekplmemlkjljcfloiemho)

Source available at https://github.com/webrender/trello-collapse-lists

Answer (score 2):

I needed this myself, so I wrote https://github.com/shesek/trello-hide-lists. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, it is possible to hide (archive) and show entire lists in Trello.

To hide a list, open the list's menu (hover over the list's name and you'll see a little triangle appear, click that and you'll see the list's menu). From the menu, choose **Archive This List**. The list and all of the cards on the list will be hidden, but they are not deleted, you can get them back.

The show an archived list, open the board's menu (click on the little Trello icon to the left of the board's name). From the menu, choose **Archived Items**. From there, find your list, and click **Send to Board** to return the list and all of its cards back to the board.

Comment: We are also tracking a feature request for *Collapsible Lists*. These will allow you to use more screen real estate by collapsing lists that don't apply to you. Email us at feature-ideas@trello.com to express your support.

Comment: Obviously, by hide and show, I didn't mean archive. That's not the intended workflow at all. Hide is something. Archive is other thing. :) Rich Armstrong comment was indeed what I'm looking for. If someone could reply that, at the moment, that's not possible, I could make that answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I too felt this was needed, but unfortunately shesek's code doesn't work anymore. I quickly put this together which runs fine (right now) in Chrome. If Trello changes their code around it'll probably stop working as well though.

Anyway, this adds a tiny ×-symbol to the top left of every list which hides the list on click. It could definitely be improved with some localStorage or cookies, but for now it's OK to clean the board up when I keep Trello open for a whole work session.

```
(function () {
    var closeList = function (list) {
        list.style.transition   = 'max-height 1s ease-in-out, max-width .2s 1s ease-in-out';
        list.style.maxHeight    = '4px';
        list.style.maxWidth     = '4px';
    };

    var openList = function (list) {
        list.style.transition   = 'max-height .2s 1s ease-in-out, max-width .2s ease-in-out';
        list.style.overflow     = 'hidden';
        list.style.maxHeight    = '6000px';
        list.style.maxWidth     = '250px';
    };

    var lists = document.getElementById('board').querySelectorAll('div.list');

    for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
        (function () {
            var list    = lists[i];
            var close   = document.createElement('a');

            openList(list);

            close.setAttribute('href', '#');
            close.setAttribute('class', 'close');

            close.innerHTML             = '&times;';
            close.style.textDecoration  = 'none';
            close.style.position        = 'absolute';
            close.style.left            = '1px';
            close.style.top             = '-5px';

            list.appendChild(close);

            close.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                if (close.getAttribute('class') == 'close') {
                    closeList(list);
                    close.setAttribute('class', 'open');
                    close.innerHTML = 'o';
                }
                else {
                    openList(list);
                    close.setAttribute('class', 'close');
                    close.innerHTML = '&times;';
                }
            });
        })();
    }
})();
```

Comment: This works. To use it open up the trello board you want with chrome, hit F12 on your keyboard to open up the chrome developer tools, click the console tab, and paste the code above into the console. After this you will see the little Xs on the list but only for the current session. If you close and reopen it will be gone and you have to do the process again.

Comment: That code stopped working with the recent Trello update. I've posted working code here: https://github.com/shesek/trello-hide-lists/issues/1#issuecomment-199693936