# Can Trello filter by list so that only certain lists are visible

Tags: trello, trello-lists

I am setting up some projects in Trello with multiple lists organized in a way that we are focusing on one or two lists at a time. I there a way to filter so that the ones we are working on are the only ones visible?

Answer (score 2):

No.
But see [How do I hide and show entire tasks lists in Trello?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/27539/how-do-i-hide-and-show-entire-tasks-lists-in-trello) , which has

".. there is a feature request called Collapsible Lists which you can support by e-mailing feature-ideas@trello.com."

Answer (score 0):

I'm in the same need ang my google bring up this [helper used in Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-list-filter/lohpplkkfafipfinjgjfnmidmfjobkop?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

There is a list filter extension that works for me.

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/trello-list-filter/lohpplkkfafipfinjgjfnmidmfjobkop?hl=en